# Is there a minimum distance required to use FTL?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, star-wars-legends, ftl-drive

Within several sci-fi universes (Star Wars and Star Trek in particular), when a ship jumps to FTL speeds, it's to traverse across galaxies. But is there anything that says you **must** travel a certain distance in order for whatever specific device it is that powers FTL travel to work? In other words, will the drives **allow** FTL to a neighboring planet or a location inside the same solar system?

As previously stated, I'm only asking if Star Wars and/or Star Trek have ever addressed this inside their respective worlds, as I'm sure there are countless other examples. Also note that I'm asking **specifically** about the FTL **device's** limitations, and not about any one captain or group's protocol (unless they actually modified the drive to act a certain way I guess).

Canonicity is not an issue.

Comment: The [Picard Maneuver](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Picard_Maneuver)!

Comment: Is there a reason to ask about both works simultaneously? They both use different methods of (fictional) FTL.

Comment: This question would be greatly improved if it were split into separate questions for Star Wars and Star Trek.

Comment: Ugh. That's why I [asked about this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10802/75000) beforehand. :)

Comment: Questions about microjumps/in-system warp has been addressed in several questions.;

Comment: @SonOfSam - No worries. For the record, if you'd been a bit clearer in your meta question about what you were planning to ask (or had posted a precis in chat) I could have saved you the trouble :-)

Comment: @SonOfSam Your meta questions reads "I want to ask a question that involves a specific piece of technology that different sci-fi shows and movies share." Hyperdrive and Warp Drive are *not* the same technology and are *not* shared between these franchises.

Comment: @Valorum Not sure how chat works around here yet. Seems like a bunch of memes and inside jokes. Don't know if I'm cool enough yet. Maybe I'll give it a try someday. :)

Comment: @SonOfSam - Just wander in and say hi. If you want to ask a specific question, just post it and someone will almost always point you toward possible dupes if you're struggling to search...

Comment: @Valorum I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: You mean traverse across ~a~ galaxy? Inter-galactic travel is extremely rare in Star Trek, nonexistent(?) in Star Wars, etc. Stargate: Universe appeared to be the only major sci-fi franchise to explore intergalactic travel.